# Default Security Groups on Site Creation from Web Service

Tags: web-services, security

I am creating SharePoint Team Sites using SharePoint Web Services as I cannot use the object model for this solution (I do not have SharePoint installed on the server where the sites are created from). The sites create fine but I do not have the default "Members", "Visitors" and "Owners" groups. I know using the SharePoint Object Model you can use the SPWeb.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups method. How would you be able to perform a similar operation using SharePoint Web Services?

Comment: I have the Same problem, using the Web Services, Admin.CreateSite, From what i can tell, the admin.create does not by default associate the Default SharePoint groups to the Created site collection even when using a Template like Team Site which when created through SharePoint has the Groups by Default. Desperately looking for a Web Service Method that can Associate the Groups after Creation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean the SOAP or .asmx Web Services, I don't think that the option you want is exposed in any of the available operations.